# Calling a (Gazebo) service parallelly from multiple nodes/ Remapping a (Gazebo) service to a particular namespace

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic, service, nodes, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a multi robot setting (with different namespaces which work totally independent of each other, in the same empty_world) in Gazebo. I have to reset the manipulated objects after a certain time interval. I have different ROS nodes controlling the robots and the resetting objects. So I want to use gazebo/set_model_state service parallelly in all the nodes. Spawning one robot works fine as it is the only node using the service. But as soon as I launch the second node it gives me the following error from the first simulation and the second simulation starts running fine.

> rospy.service.ServiceException:
> service [/gazebo/set_model_state]
> returned no response

I'm aware that the service call executes commands in a serial manner. But I would like to call the service parallelly from all the nodes at the same time. Is this possible? I suppose this can be done if I can somehow "remap" the service like I do for the topics. That way I can specifically call the service belonging to the robot of that particular namespace. Or if I somehow clone the existing service into multiple unique services each node can call these unique nodes parallelly. But I'm not sure how this can be done. Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288916/calling-a-(gazebo)-service-parallelly-from-multiple-nodes/-remapping-a-(gazebo)-service-to-a-particular-namespace/) by [nf](https://answers.ros.org/users/34611/nf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the service call takes very less time to execute the command. I added an extra line for rospy to wait till the service is again available but just this line without adding a time like around 5 sec wasnt working.

> rospy.wait_for_service('/gazebo/set_model_state',
> 5.0)

After adding this line my error vanished and am able to execute things as I want them to. To prevent future errors i also added a try, except statements while doing the service call.

Though this doesn't answer the asked question this provided me with a quick fix to work with.

---

Originally posted by [nf](https://answers.ros.org/users/34611/nf/) with karma: 16 on 2018-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0